# How to update properties and events of dynamically cloned elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Please help me in solving this.
I do have a simple code like this.
I have total 3 columns: Experience from date, Experience to date and calculate button
When one is clicking on calculate it calculates the years,months and days.

```
 <table width="100%" id="dataTable2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Duration From</th>
    <th scope="col">Duration To</th>
    <th scope="col">Total Experience</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">
    <input id="txt_exp_from" name="txt_exp_from" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" onChange="calculate(this,'txt_exp_from','txt_exp_to');">
    <a id="a_datefrom" href="javascript:NewCal('txt_exp_from','ddmmyyyy')">
        <img id="img_datefrom" src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>
    </td>

    <td align="center">
    <input id="txt_exp_to" name="txt_exp_to" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" onChange="calculate(this,'txt_exp_from','txt_exp_to');">
    <a id="a_dateto" href="javascript:NewCal('txt_exp_to','ddmmyyyy')">
        <img id="img_dateeto" src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
    </a>
    </td>

    <td align="center">
    <p id="tp">
    <input name="btn_cal" id="btn_cal" type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate(this,'txt_exp_from','txt_exp_to');"></p>
    </td>    
  </tr>      
</table>
```

I am cloning the entire row for someone who wants to add one or more experience details. During cloning i am setting the name and ids of control using this javascript code:

```
    var x=document.getElementById('dataTable2');//Assume this as table name
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;//taking the length, Intially 1
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;//The first column for Sr. No. in table
    var inp5 = new_row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        inp5.id += len;
        inp5.value = '';
        inp5.name+= len;

        var a1 = new_row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        a1.id += len;
        a1.href="javascript:NewCal('"+inp5.id+"','ddmmyyyy')";

        var inp6 = new_row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        inp6.id += len;
        inp6.value = '';
        inp6.name+= len;

        var a1 = new_row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        a1.id += len;
        a1.href="javascript:NewCal('"+inp6.id+"','ddmmyyyy')";

        var inp7 = new_row.cells[7].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        inp7.id += len;
        inp7.name+= len;
        inp7.value = 'Calculate';
        inp7.onclick="calculate(this,'"+inp5.id+"','"+inp6.id+"');";
        x.appendChild(new_row );
```

---

**(1) How can i dynamically change the onchange property of "txt_exp_from" like this: onChange="calculate(this,'txt_exp_from2','txt_exp_to2') ?

(2) How can i change the same for the textbox "txt_exp_to" ?

(3) How can i change the same for button btn_cal2 onclick event to ="calculate(this,'txt_exp_from2','txt_exp_to2')"

---

I know only JavaScript. What should I do? Something which could update the property values plus the event parameters too dynamically for the cloned elements?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone content like this your best bet is probably to avoid hard-coding element ids into the event handlers - instead the handlers should work out the appropriate relative ids or controls based on their own id or context.

e.g.

```
<input id="txt_exp_from" name="txt_exp_from" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" onChange="calculate(this, this.id, this.id.replace('_from','_to'));">
```

or, if you added a data-index property at **tr** level :

```
<input id="txt_exp_from" name="txt_exp_from" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" onChange="calculate(this, this.id, 'txt_exp_to' + this.parentElement.parentElement.dataset-index);">
```

or, if you set CSS class toControl on txt_exp_to, something like :

```
<input id="txt_exp_from" name="txt_exp_from" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" onChange="calculate(this, this.id, this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('toControl')[0].id);">
```

Many would argue that it would be better to avoid inline event handlers in this scenario and register event handlers explicitly though.